# How can I get the path from start to a specified node?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have file like this.

| From | To |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 3 | 5 |
| 4 | 6 |
| 5 | 7 |
| 6 | 8 |

**How can I find the path for each point?**

For eg:

For 3 is [(1,2), (2,3)]

for 8 is `[(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,6),(6,8)]`

Any Help would be appreciable!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Path starting from 1 to 8?

Comment: @AmitVikramSingh Yes, path from 1 to any bus

Comment: You dont need pandas but you can set your data structure as `dict()` and use bfs or dfs

Comment: @user1462442 I just want to find the path from a start to any required point.

Comment: This has nothing to do with pandas. Look up some path finding algorithms like [Dijkstra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) and [A*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm)

Comment: For 8 isn't it `[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5), (4, 6), (5, 7), (6, 8)]` instead of `[(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,6),(6,8)]`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505431/breadth-first-search-and-depth-first-search
https://trykv.medium.com/algorithms-on-graphs-lets-talk-depth-first-search-dfs-and-breadth-first-search-bfs-5250c31d831a

It doesn't matter. The only difference is adding another function argument. You created a classic pathfinding problem

Comment: @AnuragDabas the path for 8 doesnot need (3,5) and (5,7) So

Comment: What happened when you tried putting `python find path in graph` into a search engine?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I am a beginner didn't know of these modules, so tried to do on my way.

Answer (score 3):

A data structure like dict is more suitable to store the graph information.

Set `To` as index, so that given a node `x` we can find out prev node using `df.loc[x, 'From']`. Start from the destination node and keep moving to the previous node until you get `1(source node)`.

Use:

```
df = df.set_index('To')
x = 8
output = []
while x!=1:
    y = df.loc[x, 'From']
    output = [(y, x)] + output
    x = y
```

Prints:

```
>>> output
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 6), (6, 8)]
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried moving from forward to backward and that was must difficult since there can be multiple branches. I didn't think about the reverse that the last one would have only one point prior to it. It worked

Comment: [BFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23477921/bfs-algorithm-in-python) is the most used algorithm for such purposes. However in your case, graph is a Tree which means there is a unique path from source to destination and we also have the access to back pointer from a node to its parent node, so here we can simply do backtracking(I hope it's correct name).

Answer (score 2):

If it suits your purpose, you can resort to a "specialized" package for working with graphs. I'll give an example with `networkx`. In the example:

- I've taken the data you provided;
- converted it to `networkx` Graph;
- printed a list of the nodes (not the edges, note) that make your path;
- drawn a plot and saved it to a `.png` file.

```
import networkx
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5), (4, 6), (6, 8)],
                  columns=['from', 'to'])

g = networkx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='from', target='to')

# Print a list of the nodes in the path from 1 to 8
print(networkx.shortest_path(g, source=1, target=8))

# Plot the graph
networkx.draw_networkx(g)
plt.savefig("test.png", format="PNG")
```